# Publishing .net core 2.2 app online and configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to publish .net core app online, however I'm not sure if I'm doing the publish procedure correctly.

This is the output of my publish:

[image]

When running the app locally this is the default view:

[image]

I'm not sure how to deploy the app online, I tried to push the files from the publish output but I'm getting this screen:

[image]

These are the application properties:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install .Net Core Runtime on your server?

Comment: Or the hosting bundle that contains the IIS module? also check specifically for the api/values URL if the project doesn't contain any other pages which cases the 404

Comment: The deployment instructions are clearly documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iis-configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the application locally, the URL has the controller/action route specified:

https://localhost:44394**/api/values**

But the error screen shot is a base URL without a route:

http://api.mywebsite.com

Try adding the route to the published website URL and see if you can reach your app that way:

http://api.mywebsite.com/**api/values**

There should be a way to make the base URL automatically route to the values controller.  Bonus points if anyone knows how to do that.